# How to make a huge loop for checking condition in dataframe run faster in mac

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization

I need to calculate a huge table value (157954 rows and 365 columns) by checking three conditions in a dataframe with 11 mil rows. Do you have any way to speed up the calculation, which is taking more than 10 hours now?

[image]

I have 367 stations in total.

```py
for station in stations:
    no_pickup_array = []
    for time_point in data_matrix['Timestamp']:
        time_point_2 = time_point + timedelta(minutes=15)
        no_pickup = len(dataframe[(time_point <= dataframe["departure"]) & (dataframe["departure"] < time_point_2) 
                        & (dataframe['departure_name'] == station)])
        no_pickup_array.append(no_pickup)
    print(f"Station name: {station}")
    data_matrix[station] = no_pickup_array
```

I appreciate any of your help.

@ To all: Thank you for your comments, I add more info for my problem.

[image: This is the dataframe to check conditions]

Each row of dataframe is info of each renting bike. I want to create a matrix with number of bikes picked up at each station for each 15 minutes interval. Then I also want to calculate the average speed, average time,.. as well.

The solution from @Jérôme Richard could reduce the number of calculations, but I still struggle to understand and implement indexing steps and apply logarithmic search or binary search.

```py
 index = {name: df for name, df.sort_values('departure')['departure'].to_numpy() in dataframe.groupby('departure_name')}
# code @Jérôme Richard recommended
```

Comment: Hello could you please provide more info regarding where the stations are saved, how the stations and timepoints correlate and what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you verified this code works on a smaller section of your data? Lines 5-6 look like they might not do what you want them to.

Comment: @RichardKraus: I have 11 mil records of pick up bikes. I'm calculating the number of bikes picking up at each station in 15 mins interval.

Comment: @typecasto: could you point out the problem which you are seeing? It returns some number but I haven't verified it yet.

Comment: @Dustin went ahead and posted it as an answer, since there's way too much for a comment (plus it does answer the question)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the right-hand-side of the `no_pickup` assignment expression which is **algorithmically inefficient** because it makes a *linear search* while a **logarithmic search** is possible.

The first thing to do is to do a `groupby` of `dataframe` so to build an **index** enabling to fetch the dataframe subset having a given name. Then, you can **sort** each dataframe subset by departure so to be able to perform a **binary search** enabling you to know the number of item fitting the condition.

The index can be built with something like:

```py
index = {name: df for name, df.sort_values('departure')['departure'].to_numpy() in dataframe.groupby('departure_name')}
```

Finally, you can do the binary search with two `np.searchsorted` on `index[station]`: one to know the starting index and one to know the ending index. You can get the length with a simple subtraction of the two.

Note that you may need some tweak since I am not sure the above code will works on your dataset but it is hard to know without an example of code generating the inputs.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Jérôme Richard I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You're indexing the dataframe list with a boolean (which will be zero or one, so you're only ever going to get the length of the first or second element) instead of a number. It's going to get evaluated like so:

```py
len(dataframe[(time_point <= dataframe["departure"]) & (dataframe["departure"] < time_point_2) & (dataframe['departure_name'] == station)])
len(dataframe[True & False & True]) # let's just say the variables work out like this
len(dataframe[False])
len(dataframe[0])
```

This probably isn't the behavior you're after. (let me know what you're trying to do in a comment and I'll try to help out more.)

In terms of code speed specifically, `&` is bitwise "AND", in python the boolean operators are written out as `and`, `or`, and `not`. Using `and` here would speed up your code, since python only evaluates parts of boolean expressions where they're needed, e.g.

```py
from time import sleep
def slow_function():
    sleep(3)
    return False

# This line doesn't take 3 seconds to run as you may expect.
# Python sees "False and" and is smart enough to realize that whatever comes after is irrelevant. 
# No matter what comes after "False and", it's never going to make the first half True.
# So, python doesn't bother evaluating it, and saves 3 seconds in the process.
False and slow_function()

# Some more examples that show python doesn't evaluate the right half unless it needs to
False and print("hi")
False and asdfasdfasdf
False and 42/0

# The same does not happen here. These are bitwise operators, expected to be applied to numbers.
# While it does produce the correct result for boolean inputs, it's going to be slower,
# since it can't rely on the same optimization.
False & slow_function()

# Of course, both of these still take 3 seconds, since the right half has to be evaluated either way.
True and slow_function()
True & slow_function()
```

Comment: Oh, this is a nice treat to reduce computational efforts. I will move the conditions to check station as the first condition.